# Angular2 shared.module and directive make reusable

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular6, angular2-directives

Couldn't reusable this `dropdownDirective` with this structure, Please help

There is `dropdown` in each page and also in the header component. I don't know how to import dropdownDirective and use the dropdown function in each page and blocks in this scenario

**My experiments** 
1) When I tried to import dropdownDirective to app.module, then its work on header component but not working in pages

2) When I tried to import dropdownDirective to shared.module and its import to feature module, then It's working all page components but not work in the header component

**html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**Folder strcture**

```
--app
  ---header
     header.components.ts
  ---footer
     footer.components.ts

  ---pages
     ---dashboard
        dashboard.modules.ts
        ---create
           create.components.ts
        ******other pages
     ---product
        product.modules.ts
        ---list
           list.components.ts
        ******other pages

  ---shared
     ---dropdownDirective
        dropdownDirective.ts

  app.module.ts
```

Answer (score 2):

To access component or directive in multiple modules we need to create a separate common module, here you have created shared module. So declare `DropdownDirective` in `SharedModule` and export it there

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    DropdownDirective
  ],
  exports: [
    DropdownDirective
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

Now import `SharedModule` in both `AppModule` and Feature Modules.

Comment: Now it works, May I ask now all exported components and directives are included in app.module even CommonModule also, Is that good way? @Ankit Prajapati

Comment: Because you want to access `DropdownDirective` in `HeaderComponent`, and `HeaderComponent` is declared in `AppModule`. To access directive you have to import SharedModule in AppModule also. But instead of this we can create one `LayoutModule` which can include `HeaderCompoent` and `SidebarCompoent`, import the SharedModule here, and export `HeaderCompoent` & `SidebarComponent` from here. Now Import `LayoutModule` in `AppModule`. This way you can make proper code structure

Comment: Just tried to change the structure as you said - but Error - compiler.js:2175 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
'app-header' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-header' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-header' i

Comment: have you exported `HeaderComponent` from `LayoutModule` ?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you try to create a shared.module in your structure.

```
---shared
  ---dropdownDirective
  --shared.module.ts
```

Then you can import it where ever you need the shared module should also export the directive. In app.module and in other modules.

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        MyDirective
    ],

    exports: [
        MyDirective
    ]
})
export class SharedModule{}
```

This may also help: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/10982

Comment: Now it works, May I ask now all exported components and directives are included in app.module even CommonModule also, Is that good way?